Secure-erase an nvme SSD with nvme-cli
I used to secure my old computers by using dd and checking with an hex editor.
Now I want to erase a computer with an nvme drive.
I roamed the web to try to understand how it works.
My drive is a Samsung 970 EVO nvme SSD:
sudo nvme list
Node                  Generic               SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
--------------------- --------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1          /dev/ng0n1            S467NX0M124415Y      Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB                  1         746.73  GB /   1.00  TB    512   B +  0 B   2B2QEXE7

In the first place, I have determined what format features are supported by this precise drive:
sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Format NVM"

sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Crypto Erase"

sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Sanitize"

Pour Samsung SSD 970 EVO (Entroware Athena) :

sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Format NVM"
  [1:1] : 0x1   Format NVM Supported
  [3:3] : 0 Format NVM Broadcast NSID (FFFFFFFFh) Supported

sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Crypto Erase"
    [0:0] : 0   Crypto Erase Sanitize Operation Not Supported
  [2:2] : 0x1   Crypto Erase Supported as part of Secure Erase
  [1:1] : 0 Crypto Erase Applies to Single Namespace(s)

sudo nvme id-ctrl -H /dev/nvme0 | grep "Sanitize"
  [29:29] : 0   No-Deallocate After Sanitize bit in Sanitize command Supported
    [2:2] : 0   Overwrite Sanitize Operation Not Supported
    [1:1] : 0   Block Erase Sanitize Operation Not Supported
    [0:0] : 0   Crypto Erase Sanitize Operation Not Supported

And so, Format is supported,
Format Crypto (mode 2) is supported,
But Sanitize is not supported.
At this point, there are things I don't understand.
In this page:
https://tinyapps.org/docs/nvme-secure-erase.html
are detailed 3 modes of the nvme-cli format command:
Mode 0: No secure erase operation requested
1) Does it mean that it's a simple formating, meaning wiping the file tables and the partition but leaving the data on the drive?
Mode 1: User Data Erase: All user data shall be erased, contents of the user data after the erase is indeterminate (e.g., the user data may be zero filled, one filled, etc).
2) Does it mean that a dd kind of process is used and that all user data (not the entire drive as with dd) are replaced with random characters?
The controller may perform a cryptographic erase when a User Data Erase is requested if all user data is encrypted.
3) By "if all user data is encrypted", does it mean: if during the installation of linux you had requested the encryption of the home?
Mode 2: Cryptographic Erase: All user data shall be erased cryptographically. This is accomplished by deleting the encryption key.
4) Here where does the encryption of the data come from?
5) And what is the difference between mode 2 and mode 1bis ("with a cryptographic erase")?
In all websites the same words and the same formulas are repeated but not explained.
If someone masters these things and can explain them in plain English, it would be great!

Bit more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing#NVMe_drive
